# What is 'acme_directory_url' in the letsencrypt-aws config?

Tags: lets-encrypt

The documentation says it "defaults to Let's Encrypt production" but I'm unsure what it actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I should answer this as it's been sitting unanswered.

https://github.com/alex/letsencrypt-aws/blob/master/letsencrypt-aws.py#L25 as the code says the default value is`https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` which is the live let's encrypt directory.

There's also a staging directory that allows the generation of invalid certificates for testing purposes https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/ so therefor setting the value to `https://acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` should use the staging servers